# phplibsec waiting time expired

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm afraid this question looks trivial, but I'm working on it one entire day and can't understand what happen.

Im using the SSH library phpseclib to connect to a ssh host, and after that, doing a telnet connection

```
    <?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . "\\" . 'phpseclib');
    include('Net/SSH2.php');


    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.10.10.10');

    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password'))
        {
        exit('Login Failed');
        }

    echo $ssh->read('$');
    echo "<hr />";

    echo $ssh->write("telnet 10.10.20.20\n");
    echo "<hr />";

    echo $ssh->read('User');
    echo "<hr />";

    echo $ssh->write('admin\n');
    echo"<hr />";

    echo $ssh->read('Password');
    $ssh->write('admin\n');
    ?>
```

Well, debugging it stops after detect User. I think I send the user, but I wait forever for the string Password.

The exit I have in HTML code is the following

```
    Last login: Tue Dec 2 14:06:11 2014 from 10.10.10.2 $1 
    telnet 10.10.20.20 Telnet escape character is 'off'. Trying 10.10.20.20...         
    Connected to 10.10.20.20. Escape character is 'off'. ****Hello User1
    Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\php\pear\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 2699
```

Well, note that 1 appears twice, after the line of last login and the Hello User, that was not intentioned.

Well, any ideas?

On the other hand, I tried to use "exec" command, but with not success too.

Comment: What happens if you do that manually?

Comment: @SenseException That's what I made on this example, it is? I really don't know why it is not working :(

Comment: Well I think what's happening. A user write this one two years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727467/phpseclib-cant-connect-to-cisco-switch and well, the problem is that Telnet is a process running under SSH sessions, (not like ls-la, where the process terminates instantly and come back to the SSH sessions). If there is interaction with the use, like Telnet, I can't wait to read something because I'm still inside the telnet process. Quite complex. I should find other solution.

Comment: I would do `$ssh->setTimeout()` and then echo out the result. Maybe pass the output through `urlencode()` too. For example, maybe the string that's being returned to you is "password", with a lower case 'p', instead of "Password", with an upper case 'P'.